# Why are Vuetify component options unelectable with specific key names?

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, key, vuetify.js

There exists an array of objects like so:

```
arrOfObjs = [
    {
        "id": 19,
        "grid_id": 3,
        "order": 4,
        "header": "Duration",
        "input": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "= "
            },
            {
                "type": "mention",
                "attrs": {
                    "id": 18,
                    "data": "Duration",
                }
            }
        ],
        "axis_type": "series",
        "grouped": null,
        "agg_func": null
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "grid_id": 3,
        "order": 5,
        "header": "Duration2",
        "input": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "= "
            },
            {
                "type": "mention",
                "attrs": {
                    "id": 18,
                    "data": "Duration",
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "*2"
            }
        ],
        "axis_type": "series",
        "grouped": null,
        "agg_func": null
    }
]
```

I have a v-autocomplete where each of the 'items' represents an object in arrOfObjs:

```
<v-autocomplete
    :items="arrOfObjs"
    :item-text="item => `${item.header}`"
    return-object
    chips multiple solo flat
/>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

The issue is with the key 'Header' in each object within arrOfObjs. Changing this to any other name e.g. 'Headers' or 'efbrvf' will make the v-autocomplete options selectable:

[image]

Why is this the case and how can I make it so that 'Header' is accepted (It also yields the same result for v-select)?

Comment: From vuetify docs `Objects that have a header or divider property are considered special cases and generate a list header or divider; these items are not selectable.` https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props

Answer (score 0):

Just as Radeanu said on his comment, objects that have a **header** or **divider** property are considered special cases. Currently there's no way to change that behaivor in vuetify, so, you'll need to either rename/remove that property from your objects array.

```js
    this.arrOfObjs.forEach( function(data) {
        data['headers'] = data['header']
        delete data['header'];
    });
```